# How to get app client CFBundleShortVersionString from iOS framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, plist

I am implementing framework. I need to know client bundle short version (**CFBundleShortVersionString**) from the framework perspective.

How to get iOS app CFBundleShortVersionString from the framework?

Answer (score 1):

Use below to get version:

```
for(NSBundle *bundel in [NSBundle allFrameworks]){
        if([bundel.bundlePath.lastPathComponent isEqualToString:@"yourframek_name.framework"]){
            version = [bundel objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to do it opposite way. From the framework get app bundle short version.

Answer (score 0):

To access the apps bundle you can always use [NSBundle mainBundle].
So to access apps shortVersionString, just call:

```
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
[appBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```